# How to properly use external state in react/storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I am using the great `storybook/react`, but I have encountered a problem.

I have a lot of components that rely on props (are stateless), so in my real-world app I have containers components that keep state.

For example, I have a `<Toggle />`, as you can see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ovo7jw4wk6) that get value from its parent and calls the onChange from its props to change it. I want to have this behavior in my storybook, but don't how to do it:

```
storiesOf('Toggle', module).add('', () => (
  <Toggle name="toggle" checked={/*  what here ? */} onChange={/* what here ? */} />
))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the storyebook state addons, like this one I published some time ago https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sambego/storybook-state

Your code might look like the following, where the `checked` property will be passed automatically from the store, and the `onChange` method will update the store.

```js
const store = new Store({
    checked: true,
});

storiesOf('Toggle', module)
    .addDecorator(StateDecorator(store))
    .add('', () => (
        <Toggle name="toggle" onChange={() => store.set({checked: store.get('checked')})} />
    ))
```